# Why is a property inside aFragment, which is in a ViewPager after showing a Dialog not initialized any more?

Tags: android, kotlin

As you can see in the images I have a **TabLayout** and a **Viewpager**.

I have one **Fragment for Products** and one for Categories. In my **onViewCreated** Method I am **setting the progressBar visible.** The **progressBar property** is **initialized** in the **onViewCreated** Method before accessing the ProgressBar.

As you can see in the image the ProgressBar is set successfully to visible. The products are loaded and afterwards the ProgressBar is set invisible again.

When I hit the Floating Action Button I am opening a **Dialog**, which is extending the *DialogFragment* class.

The Main Class, which is containing the TabView and the ViewPager is implementing the ***ProductDialog.ProductDialogEventListener***. This means, when I am hitting the save Button the Method onProductAdded is called in the Main Class.

This Method however is calling a Method in the productFragment Class to add the new Product to the list inside the fragment. When the ProgressBar is set visible now, the I receive a UninitializedPropertyAccessException because the progressBar Property is not initialized.

I don't understand it, because I have already initialized and used it before.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is some code:

The ProductDialog:

```
class ProductDialog : DialogFragment() {

    lateinit var editTextTitle: EditText
    lateinit var editTextSpecialText: EditText
    lateinit var editTextDescription: EditText
    lateinit var radioButtonMen: RadioButton
    lateinit var radioButtonWomen: RadioButton
    lateinit var radioButtonUnisex: RadioButton
    lateinit var productDialog: AlertDialog
    lateinit var productDialogEventListener: ProductDialogEventListener
    lateinit var apiOperations: ApiOperations

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_product_dialog,null)
        builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Produkt erstellen")
            .setPositiveButton("Speichern") { _, _ -> saveProductRequest()}
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel) { _, _ ->
                dialog.cancel()
            }
        setViews(view)
        setValues(view)
        productDialog = builder.create()
        return productDialog
    }

    interface ProductDialogEventListener{
        val onProductAdded: (variant:Product)->Unit
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        try {
            productDialogEventListener = context as ProductDialogEventListener
        }catch (exception: ClassCastException){
            throw exception
        }
    }

    private fun onProductSaved(id:String){
        productDialogEventListener.onProductAdded(Product(id.toInt(),editTextTitle.text.toString(),editTextSpecialText.text.toString(),editTextDescription.text.toString(),getCheckedGender()))
    }
```

The Main Activity (OverviewActivity)

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.TableLayout
import android.widget.Toast

class OverviewActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ProductDialog.ProductDialogEventListener, CategoryDialog.CategoryDialogListener {
    private lateinit var listViewCategories: ListView
    private lateinit var apiOperations: ApiOperations
    private lateinit var progressBarCategories: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var addCategoryButton: FloatingActionButton
    private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
    private lateinit var viewPager : ViewPager
    private var categories = ArrayList<Category>()
    private val productsFragment = ProductsFragment()
    private val categoriesFragment = CategoriesFragment()

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        setCategories()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview)
        setViews()
        setViewPager()
        setValues()
    }

    private fun setViews(){
        listViewCategories = findViewById(R.id.listViewCategories)
        addCategoryButton = findViewById(R.id.add_category_button)
        progressBarCategories = findViewById(R.id.progressCategories)
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
    }

    private fun setViewPager(){
        val fragmentList = listOf(productsFragment,categoriesFragment)
        val overViewPageViewAdapter = OverViewPageViewAdapter(supportFragmentManager,tabLayout.tabCount)
        viewPager.adapter = overViewPageViewAdapter
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : OnTabSelectedListener{
            override fun onTabReselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            }

            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                viewPager.currentItem = tab.position
            }
        })
    }

    private fun setValues(){
        apiOperations = ApiOperations(applicationContext)
    }

    private fun setProgressBarVisible(visible: Boolean, progressBar: ProgressBar){
        when(visible){
            true -> progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            else -> progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    fun addNewProductButtonClicked(view:View){
        val dialog = ProductDialog()
        dialog.show(supportFragmentManager,"New Product")
    }
    
    override val onProductAdded: (product: Product) -> Unit
        get() = {product ->
            productsFragment.onProductAdded(product)
        }
    }
```

And finally the productFragment Class

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.Toast

class ProductsFragment :Fragment(){

    lateinit var apiOperations: ApiOperations
    lateinit var listViewProducts: ListView
    lateinit var addProductButton: FloatingActionButton
    lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
    private var products = ArrayList<Product>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.products_fragment_layout,container,false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        apiOperations = ApiOperations(view.context)
        setViews(view)
        setProducts(view)
    }


    private fun setViews(view: View){
        listViewProducts = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewProducts)
        addProductButton = view.findViewById(R.id.add_product_button)
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular)
    }

    private fun updateProductList(view: View,newList:ArrayList<Product>){
        Toast.makeText(context,"settingProgressbar visible",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        setProgressBarVisible(true)
        products = newList
        listViewProducts.adapter = ProductListViewAdapter(view,
            products,::deleteProduct)
        listViewProducts.setOnItemClickListener{ _, _, position, _ ->
            val product: Product = listViewProducts.adapter.getItem(position) as Product
            openProductActivity(product)
        }
        setProgressBarVisible(false)
    }


    private fun setProducts(view: View){
        setProgressBarVisible(true)
        apiOperations.getProducts(
            { newList -> updateProductList(view,newList)},
            {
                setProgressBarVisible(false)
                Toast.makeText(context,"Produkte konnten nicht geladen werden!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        )
    }

    fun addNewProductButtonClicked(view:View){
        val dialog = ProductDialog()
        dialog.show(fragmentManager,"New Product")
    }

    private fun deleteProduct(view: View,productId: Int){
        setProgressBarVisible(true)
        apiOperations.deleteProduct(productId,{
            products.removeAll { product -> product.id == productId }
            updateProductList(view,products)
            setProgressBarVisible(false)
            Toast.makeText(view.context,"Produkt wurde gelöscht!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        },
            {
                Toast.makeText(view.context, "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                setProgressBarVisible(false)
            }
        )
    }

    private fun openProductActivity(product: Product){
        val intent = Intent(view?.context, ProductActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("product",product)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun setProgressBarVisible(visible: Boolean){
        if(progressBar==null){
            progressBar = view!!.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)
        }
        Toast.makeText(context,"setProgressbar called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        when(visible){
            true -> progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            else -> progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

     fun onProductAdded(product: Product) {
            setProgressBarVisible(true)
            products.add(product)
            Toast.makeText(context,products.size.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Toast.makeText(context,"Neues Produkt " + product.title + " hinzugefügt!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            setProgressBarVisible(false)
        }
}
```

Also I added following Code in the other Fragement. There I have the same issue. It seems like getView() (in Kotlin only **view**) results in null and hence is not working. Why is this happening. I also tried to reset the values in onResume as recommended in the comments but neither onPause or onResume is called after closing the DialogFragment.

I can't imagine that I am the only one having this problem.

```
    fun onCategoryAdded(category: Category){
        Log.i("fragment","onCategoryAdded called")
        if(categories === null){
            Log.i("fragment", "categories is null")
        }
        if(view == null){
            Log.i("fragment", "view is null")
        }
        if(categories!=null && view!= null){
            categories.add(category)
            updateCategoriesList(view!!.context,categories)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Avoid using lateintit where you not sure if it will be initialized or else will not able to maintain its state. Rather make variable nullable and give it a try!

Comment: I guess this is not the solution as I want to know why this problem is occurring any way. But thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was accessing the two Fragments initialized at the beginning of the class.

```
private val productsFragment = ProductsFragment()
private val categoriesFragment = CategoriesFragment()
```

And that was very stupid, because these were not the fragments that were add to the ViewPager. In the ViewPagerAdapter the Fragments were created and added to the ViewPager.

Thats why I added two methods to the adapter which return the Fragment instances.
In the holding Activity I am calling those before accessing the fragment instances now. And the problem is solved.

The problem was sitting in front of the keyboard.

```
class OverViewPageViewAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, private var tabCount: Int) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    private var productFragment = ProductsFragment()
    private var categoriesFragment = CategoriesFragment()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {

        return when (position) {
            0 -> productFragment
            1 -> categoriesFragment
            else -> null
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return tabCount
    }

    fun getCategoriesFragmentInstance(): CategoriesFragment{
        return categoriesFragment
    }

    fun getProductFragmentInstance(): ProductsFragment{
        return productFragment
    }


}
```

```
    override val onProductAdded: (product: Product) -> Unit
        get() = {
            product ->
            val adapter: OverViewPageViewAdapter = viewPager.adapter as OverViewPageViewAdapter
            adapter.getProductFragmentInstance().onProductAdded(product)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the progressbar inside your activity instead your fragment and then access the progressbar from both your fragments. By doing so, you won't face the error.

Comment: Probably yes. But I want to know why this is even happening. I would be really happy if someone could explain me why this behaviour is happening

Comment: when you open a dialog, your activity goes to onPause() state. So on your dialog button click, your dialog dismisses and then your activity will resume and then your farment will resume as well, so everything has be initialized again. May be, your progressbar is getting called before all these processes are finished.

Comment: Well I added these onResume and onPause in the Holding Activity but they are not called when I open or close the Dialog.

Comment: override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.i("fragment","Overview onResume called")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.i("fragment","Overview onPause called")
    }

```